# Determining the boundary of a group within a Flare/Rive object in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, rive

I have a big Flare/Rive object. When the user clicks on the Flare object I want to know where the user clicked and how far the click is from specific nodes in the tree of the Flare object to animate the clicked features of the tree.

How do I access the information about the boundary of the nodes in the tree of the Flare object?

Comment: I haven't used Flare/Rive before, but usually we can get this kind of information from the underling `RenderObject` and/or `context`.

Comment: You can put gesture detector above it in stack same as the size of flare widget and get position from gesture detector widget.

Comment: @SanketVekariya Using the gesture dectector is indeed not complicated. It seems more complicated to me to access the information about where the individual objects within the FlareActor happen to be positioned.

Comment: It seems currently this feature is not available. You should open feature request for this. :)